# Calabash Android console not showing any id

Tags: android, xamarin, calabash

I'm using calabash-android version 0.5.5 console to interact with my app and everything runs fine except for the fact that almost none of my elements have an id. The app I'm working with was made with Titanium and the elements I'm searching for do have id set in my code.

When I print all the views' ids like this  `query("*",:id)` I'm only getting `NoResourceEntry` and nil. For example:

```
[ 0] nil,
[ 1] "NoResourceEntry-86",
[ 2] "NoResourceEntry-87",
[ 3] "NoResourceEntry-88",
[ 4] nil,
[ 5] nil
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this problem by using the accessibilityLabel property as explained in this issue:

https://github.com/appersonlabs/TiCalabash/issues/9

add the accessibilityLabel to your element matching the element's id

```
<View id="myView" accessibilityLabel="myView">
 ...                
</View>
```

and then you can query it from the calabash-android console

```
query("* marked:'myView.'")
```

which should return an array of matching elements

```
[0] {
    "class" => "org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout",
    "tag" => nil,
    "description" => "org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiCompositeLayout{3f90638 V.E...CL. ........ 0,0-205,173 #14}",
    "id" => "NoResourceEntry-20",
    "visible" => true,
    "rect" => {
          "height" => 173,
           "width" => 205,
               "y" => 1621,
               "x" => 0,
        "center_x" => 102,
        "center_y" => 1707
    },
               "enabled" => true,
    "contentDescription" => "myView."
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
query("*").map{|e| e['id']}
```

Comment: I'm getting the exact same results with `query("*").map{|e| e['id']}`

Comment: does it have anything to do with Titanium itself?? I noticed the elements ids used in Titanium are not passed to the compiled iOS and Android native projects. I already tried unsuccessfully to set accessibility labels in order to have a way to have a possibility of identifying my elements uniquely but that didn't work. The `nil` or `NoResourceEntry-XY` appears when I'm querying Android elements. When I'm querying iOS elements with `query("view", :marked)` I get `[i] "******"` for every element with i as the element number

Comment: `query('view', :marked)` is the same as calling `marked` on the every view.  In Objective-C terms, `UIView` does not respond to `marked` so you get "******".  In Java, you would get a `NotSuchMethod` Exception.